Show which operators are unitary equivalent
I am trying to figure out which of these operators are unitary equivalent. $$1.\; t^3 x(t), \,\mathbf{L}^2[0, 1]\\ 2.\; (1-t)x(t),\,\mathbf{L}^2[0, 1]\\ 3. |t|x(t),\,  \mathbf{L}^2[-1, 1]$$
Obviously 1 is not unitary equivalent to 2 and 3 since its norm is different. But what about others?

You should make it clearer exactly what the operator is. For instance, with 1 you presumably mean to refer to the multiplication operator $T(x) = t^3x(t)$

All the operators in question have norm $1$.

$1$ and $2$ are unitarily equivalent, since both generates the von Neumann algebra $L^\infty[0, 1] \subset B(L^2[0, 1])$, so the result follows from the spectral theorem. Indeed, an explicit unitary can be given by $u: L^2[0, 1] \to L^2[0, 1]$,
$$[u(f)](t) = \sqrt{3}tf(1-t^3)$$
I’ll leave it to you to verify that $u$ is indeed a unitary operator and that $u^\ast M_{t^3} u = M_{1-t}$.
$3$ is not unitarily equivalent to either $1$ or $2$. Indeed, the von Neumann algebra it generates is a proper subalgebra of $L^\infty[-1, 1] \subset B(L^2[-1, 1])$, namely the subalgebra invariant under the flip automorphism $(\sigma f)(t) = f(-t)$. In particular the von Neumann algebra it generates is not maximally abelian, as opposed to the case in either $1$ or $2$.

Thanks! Where can I read more about generators of subalgebras? I don't understand this argument really well

@ed199957 I’m not sure where you can find this exact argument, but for something of this nature, you might want to read Murphy’s “$C^\ast$-algebras and operator theory” and Conway’s “A course in operator theory”. Both contain general introductions to von Neumann algebras and proofs of the spectral theorem. I believe they also contain proofs that $L^\infty$ is maximally abelian in $B(L^2)$. That proof can also be found in Anantharaman and Popa’s “An introduction to II$_1$ factors”.

@ed199957 That $1$ and $2$ both generate $L^\infty[0, 1]$ is a consequence of weak$^\ast$ density of $C[0, 1]$ in $L^\infty[0, 1]$ (which is effectively a standard measure theory fact that can be found in most standard measure theory texts once you know what weak$^\ast$ convergence means) and Stone-Weierstrass theorem (which can be found in plenty of standard texts on general topology).

And how did you find the exact form of the unitary operator? @DavidGao

@ed199957 That wasn’t the application of any theorem. It was just trial-and-error knowing that such a unitary operator exists. To make it easier I first found a unitary that conjugates $M_{t^3}$ to $M_t$ and a unitary that conjugates $M_t$ to $M_{1-t}$, then composed them together.
